# Excel VBA to Create Header ERROR

Tags: vba, excel, header

I am currently using the below macro to customize the header based off the contents of cell B3 within spreadsheet "Reference", and have been using it sometime now.

I'm currently running into an issue where the header font is becoming very large.  The header becomes so large, that if I print the spreadsheet (which I do often with this file) it monopolizes the entire page - in other words - the header overtakes the entire print area because it's so large.

Is anyone able to see where I'm going wrong with the macro or have an idea as to why this is occurring and how to resolve this issue?

```
----

'=========================================================================
'  Custom Header based on value of specified cell
'=========================================================================

Sub HeaderFont()

ActiveSheet.PageSetup.RightHeader = "&""Calibri,bold""&11" & Sheets("Reference").Range("B3")

End Sub
```

Comment: what do you want to get ? your code runs fine, it creates the right header from the text in `Range("B3")`, and sets the font to **Calibri, bold, 11**. what is the result you want to get ?

Comment: It runs fine for the most part...but occasionally the header will appear extremely large.  I want to ensure that the header will always adhere to the standards set in the macro - Calibri, Bold, 11 size font. Are there any reasons that could cause the header to break from the macro dictated font?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you would be interested by something like the code below.
It checks the length of the string in cell "B3" and according to the length (using `Select Case`) it sets the Header font size. You will need to adjust the values inside the `Case`s to fit your needs.

```
Option Explicit

'=========================================================================
'  Custom Header based on value of specified cell
'=========================================================================

Sub HeaderFont()

Dim FntSize As Integer

Select Case Len(Sheets("Reference").Range("B3"))
    Case Is > 300 ' <-- length of string is more than 300 characters
        FntSize = 11

    Case Is > 200 ' <-- length of string is more than 200 characters
        FntSize = 12

    Case Else
        FntSize = 13

    ' you can add more Cases to have more scenarios

End Select

ActiveSheet.PageSetup.RightHeader = "&""Calibri,Bold""&" & FntSize & "" & Sheets("Reference").Range("B3")

End Sub
```

Comment: Actually just figured out why it's happening. But I need help figuring out how to avoid it from happening. I specify that the font should be size 11. From time-to-time the name of the document will begin with the number 3 (which is part of a company name)  how can I separate the font size from the header text to avoid excel from thinking the font size should be 113?

Comment: @Finley  ok, hope I've helped u